# How do I wait on three child processes?

Tags: unix, process

I'm trying to fork 3 different child processes from a parent (and running this on a UNIX box), and I want to have this requirement :

**The parent must wait till all the 3 children processes have finished executing.**

I'm using `wait` for the same .. Here's the code snippet :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int stat;
    /* ... */
```

At last, in the parent, I do this :

```
    wait (&stat);
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Question :

Do I need to call `wait` thrice or does a single call suffice?
I need to know how this works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait three times.

Answer (score 3):

You have to issue three waits.  Each `wait` blocks until a child exits or doesn't block if a child has already exited.  See [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Answer (score 0):

Side note: If you don't want to block waiting for each to terminate in turn, you can instead install a signal handler for [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD) and then call wait() to collect the return code once you know it is ready.